# How many N-digit numbers from 0 to X (in base 2N) contain no "duplicate" digits?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $X$ be a number of $3\leq N\leq8$ digits, in base $2N$ (each digit is between 0 and $2N-1$)

Assume the integers from $0$ to $N-1$ represent the uppercase alphabets in order: ('A', 'B', 'C', ... ). Likewise, the integers from $N$ to $2N-1$ represent lowercase alphabets: ('a', 'b', 'c',...) So the lowercase of $i$ is equal to : $i+N$

Knowing that "$Abac$" contains a repeated alphabet which is 'A/a, and $X$ does not contain any repeated alphabet. *How many numbers from $0$ to $X$ contain no repeated alphabet ?*

For the highest N-digit number without duplicate alphabets, for example: $\alpha=(FFFFFFFF)_{2*8}$ = "$hhhhhhhh$"; We can multiply the number of options we have for each digit and get:
$$16\times14\times12\times10\times8\times6\times4\times2$$
$$(8\times7\times6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1)\times2⁸$$
*Which is equivalent to* $$N!\times2^N$$

For $N=8$ again, the lowest number without duplicate alphabets is $\beta=(01234567)_{16}$ = "$ABCDEFGH$" and knowing that all the numbers before it, contain at least one duplicate alphabet, there is only $1$ number in $[0;\beta]$ that has no duplicate alphabets

Those are the only 2 special cases, and have easy and fast answers.

But for example: $\delta$ = "$BDacEfgH$" = $(138A4DE7)_{16}$
It is a bit complex to deduce a similar formula or algorithm that can calculate what I want when $X_{string}$ is made of alphabets that are not duplicate.

Comment: The hexadecimal (base $16$) digits  are $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F$, where $A, B, C, D, E, F$ represent $10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16$, respectively.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I see what you mean, you did not understand the post.
I am trying to solve this to code a program. And I have an array of characters where 'A', 'B', 'C',.. can be accessed with list[0], list[1], list[2]... and the lowercase letters with `list[i+N]`.

If you confuse the string letters A-H, a-h with the hexadecimal representation (numbers of BASE-16), you can take 'L', 'M', 'N',... as 0, 1, 2,.. until $N-1$ ; and the numbers from N to $2N-1$ represent 'l', 'm', 'n'...

Comment: Then you should clarify the assumptions of the problem in the question itself, not in the comments where they might be missed.

Comment: You're right, that's why I used examples that served as clarifications for the assumptions. Still, is there any way to find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ have "leading digit" $k$ and denote the rest of $X$, with digits later than $k$ "decremented", by $X'$. So if $X =$ "BDacEfgH" then $k = 1$ and $X' = $ "CabDefG". Then denoting the answer by $f_N(X)$, you have the recursion:
$$f_N(X) = k (N - 1)! 2^{N - 1} + f_{N-1}(X')$$
The first term corresponds to those numbers with leading digit $< k$, and the second term corresponds to those with leading digit $k$.